# Disabled then re-enabled user account in SBS 2003 cannot access mailbox

Tags: exchange, windows-sbs-2003, mailbox

I have a user account in SBS2003 that was disabled when the user left the company. I now have a need to access the user's mailbox. I can enable the account in Server Management no problem, and change the password successfully.

When I go to log in to webmail at https://mail.mydomain.com/exchange, I get the following error:

> You could not be logged on to Outlook
>   Web Access. Make sure your domain\user
>   name and password are correct, and
>   then try again.

I am confident that the username and password are correct. How can I access this user's exchange mailbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't already, pop into Exchange and take a look at the mailbox to make sure it's still associated with a user account (they may have been disconnected - I'm not entirely sure how SBS handles the disabling) - and that the mailbox itself isn't disabled.

Answer (score 0):

In exactly the same situation. Running the [Cleanup Agent](http://forums.msexchange.org/WHat_is_the_Mailbox_Cleanup_Agent?/m_120011400/tm.htm) on the store fixed the above problem for us, the mailbox was immediately available to us again thereafter.